# CSS constrain absolute-position div to parent size

Tags: html, css, css-position

So I need a div that covers the entirety of its parent. (Needs to be in front for event listening, so `z-index` needs be higher than parent.)

How do I do that if the parent does not have a fixed size?

E.g: https://jsfiddle.net/CypherK/hdgko1L4/

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"><!-- should be however big the container is-->
        <div class = "mask"></div> <!-- should be in front of the entire content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  height: 3em;
  width: 50%; /*could be anything*/
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.content {
  height: 1em;
  width: 100% - 6px; /*intention: as big as container, minus own borders*/
  border: 3px dashed blue;
}

.content .mask {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  height: calc(100% + 6px); /*intention: as big as content, including its borders*/
  width: calc(100% + 6px); /*intention: as big as content, including its borders*/
  margin: -3px; /*intention: place on border of parent*/
  border: 2px dotted red;
}
```

Comment: The parent element needs `position: relative`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) use `box-sizing: border-box` in order to avoid calculations about borders

2) set `position: relative` on `.content`

```css
.container {
  height: 3em;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px dashed blue;
}

.content .mask {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  right: -3px;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  top: -3px;
  border: 2px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"><!-- should be however big the container is-->
        <div class = "mask"></div> <!-- should be in front of the entire content content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Fyi: this still requires the negative margin and the + 6px on the `.content .mask` sizes to actually cover the entire `.content`. Happy to accept if you adjust accordingly. :)

Comment: @User1291 The real focus of the question is to make the parent `position: relative` as your title state.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan nope, you were correct in putting the `position: relative` on the `.content`, but the `.mask` should *also* cover the blue border.

Comment: @User1291 ok, done.